# iterating over loop in html and javascript only executing once - should be doing each time in the loop

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, jinja2

I'm trying to render a template that displays the number of reviews (1 review or xxx reviews).  I'm iterating over an object of entity instances in GAE  through jinja2, but it only executes the script the first loop through intead of each loop after that.  What's wrong with my code?

```
   <table>
    {% for each in courses_taught %}
 <tr>   
    <td id="num_reviews">           
             <script type='text/javascript'>   
        var html_output = "";               
            var review_count ={{each.num_reviews}};

                if (review_count ==1) {             
        html_output += "<a href='../course/{{each.key()}}'>1 review</a>";
        }               

        else if (review_count > 1) {
        html_output += "<a href='../detail/course/{{each.key()}}'>" + num_reviews + " reviews</a>";
        }

        else {
        html_output +="<a id='trailblazer' href='../../../review/writeReview/{{each.key()}}'>Be the trailblazer</a>";
        }

              var reviewCount = document.getElementById("num_reviews");  
      reviewCount.innerHTML = html_output;              

</script>   
</td>

 </tr>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why don't use the jinja itself without any javascript? It's not needed.

Comment: Anyway, you must give your `td` a unique id for each row, something like this: `<td id="num_reviews-{{each.unique_id}}">`. And in your javascript: `var reviewCount = document.getElementById("num_reviews-{{each.unique_id}}");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jinja solution without any extra javascript:

```
{% for each in courses_taught %}
    {{ each.num_reviews }}
    review{% if each.num_reviews > 1 %}s{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

And if you want use javascript (why?):

```
{% for each in courses_taught %}
    <tr>   
        <td id="num_reviews-{{each.unique_id}}">           
            <script type='text/javascript'>   
                var html_output = "";               
                var review_count = {{each.num_reviews}};

                if (review_count == 1) {             
                    html_output += "<a href='../course/{{each.key()}}'>1 review</a>";
                }               

                else if (review_count > 1) {
                   html_output += "<a href='../detail/course/{{each.key()}}'>" + num_reviews + " reviews</a>";
                }

                else {
                    html_output +="<a id='trailblazer' href='../../../review/writeReview/{{each.key()}}'>Be the trailblazer</a>";
                }

                var reviewCount = document.getElementById("num_reviews-{{each.unique_id}");  
                reviewCount.innerHTML = html_output;
            </script>
        </td>

    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Where `unique_id` is a unique property for each `each` element in your loop.

Comment: ohhh - didn't know that you could do that in jinja!